# cannot figure out how node works in my code

Tags: java

I'm a java beginner, and i'm trying to make a code which can created a linked loop of names in random order,so this is the code i got so far.

and i think the problem is in `assassinGame class`, but i think it should return node, so that i can use in the second class. but i dont really know how to put this name into the node.
   ** and for the second class which asks me to print the last one for each two names, which means, if the list is 1,2,3,4,5.  so it should print out 2,3,4,5, that what i thought.

** the first class is a constructor, none of them are main method.

```
private Node start;       

private static class Node {
    public int val; 
    public Node next;

    public Node(int v, Node n) {
            val = v;
            next = n;
    }
}

public AssassinGame(String[] names) {
    Random name = new Random();
    int num = name.nextInt(10)+1;

    String[] peoples = {"Bob","Jill","Tom","Brandon","Stontaigh",
                        "Loofautt","Grennoogh","Jshjnt","Zjlouv",
                        "Fabeih","Aishof","Hoir"};
    List<String> nam = Arrays.asList(peoples);
    Collections.shuffle(nam);
    int index = new Random().nextInt(nam.size());
    String anynames = nam.get(index);
    System.out.println("Your random name is" + anynames + "now!");
    return nam;
}

public void print() {
    while(nam.next!=null) { System.out.println(nam.next); }
}
```

Comment: Your method `print()` I don't know what it does, but will not work. Also, your `AssassinGame` must be, if this is your main class, `public static void AssassinGame` and should not return anything.

Comment: This is not the main method, this is a constructor

Comment: Do you know that constructors are made to assign values into your instantiated object and not to return anything? Also, you said that your goal is that if you have `1,2,3,4,5` in your array, you wanted to show `2,3,4,5`. It would be nice if it reported any error or whatever it shows in your console, that you post it here

Comment: I think that I've already lost enough time trying to understand your code, but it's imposible. I don't know if `AssassinGame` is a constructor or not, I don't know if `Node` class is declared inside `AssassinGame` or not, I don't know where `AssassinGame` class starts and where it ends, I don't know what have you tried, because you are asking about that you don't know how to set a `name` to node. You didn't instantiated a `Node` object and didn't assign values for that object... Sorry, but I can't help you only with that code. Also, will need what do you want to to get at end.

Answer (score 1):

The `print` method has a few problems:

- It should take an argument, which is the list/node to print.  At the moment it takes no arguments, so doesn't have access to a `nam` variable.
- Your `while` loop is checking that `nam.next` is not null (fine), but you are not changing `nam` within the loop.  If it's true at the start, it will be true forever and you'll get an infinite loop.  You probably want to add a line `nam = nam.next` in there.
- I think that for each instance of `nam`, you probably want to print `nam.val`.  This would definitely avoid the current bug you have where the first element of the list wouldn't be printed.

Asides from that, you're going to have problems converting your `ArrayList<String>` into a `Node`, because you've defined nodes so that they only hold an `int`.  You can use generics to make your nodes hold any type (this is exactly how Java's built-in collections work), by defining it as follows:

```
private static class Node<T>
{
    public T val; 
    public Node next;

    public Node(T v, Node n)
    {
        val = v;
        next = n;
    }
}
```

Declaring a `<T>` parameter after the class name, and replacing the declarations of `int` with `T` is all that is required.

Finally, you need a way of converting a standard Java collection into one of your Node classes.  Are you aware of an algorithm that would let you do this?  I don't want to solve that aspect for you, even though I'm happy to help with the coding specifics...